Coloring behind \cmidrule
I want the heading of my table to be a single uniform color. However because of \cmidrule there is a weird white line in between rows. Currently, my code is as follows:
\bgroup
\begin{landscape}
\rowcolors{1}{}{GhostWhite}
\begin{adjustbox}{angle=0}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{small}
\begin{xltabular}[p]{\linewidth}{XXXXXXXXXXXXX}
  \caption{Example of problems with lexical-based metrics. Similarity refers to the human-annotated semantic similarity between reference and hypothesis.}
  \label{tab:indomainresultsinitial}\\
  \toprule
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro}%
  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Portuguese}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{French}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Spanish}}\\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
  \cmidrule(lr){6-9}
  \cmidrule(lr){10-13}
  \rowcolor{Gainsboro}%
  \textbf{MODEL} & \textbf{BLEU} & \textbf{METEOR} & \textbf{COMET} & \textbf{KIWI} & \textbf{BLEU} & \textbf{METEOR} & \textbf{COMET} & \textbf{KIWI} & \textbf{BLEU} & \textbf{METEOR} & \textbf{COMET} & \textbf{KIWI}\\
  \midrule
  Solar & 00.00 & 80.00 & 80.00 & 80.00 & 80.00 & 80.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00 & 00.00\\
  \bottomrule

\end{xltabular} 
\end{small}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{landscape}
\egroup

And the output is:

Is there any way to color the white line?

Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

I'm pretty sure booktabs would say that the shading is unnecessary.

Probably you looking for the following result:

For above tablwe I use longtblr of tabularray package, which remove vertical space arounf rules defined by booktabs package.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}        

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Example of problems with lexical-based metrics. 
           Similarity refers to the human-annotated semantic similarity between reference and hypothesis.},
  label = {tab:indomainresultsinitial},
                ]{colsep  = 3pt,
                  colspec = {l 
                             *{12}{X[l]}
                             },
                  cell{1}{2,6,10}={c=4}{c},
                  cell{1}{1}={r=2}{},
                  row{1,2}= {c, font=\small\bfseries, bg=gray!30},
                  rowhead=1
                 }
    \toprule
MODEL   
    &   Portuguese
        &   &   &   &   French
                        &   &   &   &   Spanish
                                        &   &   &   \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-5}
    \cmidrule[lr]{6-9}
    \cmidrule[lr]{10-13}
        & BLEU  & METEOR    & COMET & KIWI
        & BLEU  & METEOR    & COMET & KIWI 
        & BLEU  & METEOR    & COMET & KIWI          \\
    \midrule
Solar   & 00.00 & 80.00     & 80.00 & 80.00 
        & 80.00 & 80.00     & 00.00 & 00.00 
        & 00.00 & 00.00     & 00.00 & 00.00         \\
  \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}

BTW, your question is not enirely clear. Your code fragment is a bit strange. Why you enclose table in group and use adjustbox. Also small is not an environment but switch.

With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{NiceTabular}{l*{12}{X[c]}}
\toprule
\RowStyle[nb-rows=2,rowcolor=gray!30]{\small\bfseries}
\Block{2-1}{MODEL}   
    &   \Block{1-4}{Portuguese}
        &   &   &   &   \Block{1-4}{French}
                        &   &   &   &   \Block{1-4}{Spanish}
                                        &   &   &   \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-5}
\cmidrule(lr){6-9}
\cmidrule(lr){10-13}
        & BLEU  & METEOR    & COMET & KIWI
        & BLEU  & METEOR    & COMET & KIWI 
        & BLEU  & METEOR    & COMET & KIWI          \\
\midrule
Solar   & 00.00 & 80.00     & 80.00 & 80.00 
        & 80.00 & 80.00     & 00.00 & 00.00 
        & 00.00 & 00.00     & 00.00 & 00.00         \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}


